# I recently moved into a house and it looks like a chemical has been used on the stainless steel drain and left marks. Is it possible to clean it off?

Tags: drain, steel, chemicals, stainless

[image: markings around stainless steel sink]

Markings around stainless steel sink

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately that looks like they used an acid that stripped the chrome finish off. No good way to get that back on.

Comment: It’s worth noting that sink drains like this can be replaced fairly easily. While they often come in a set with the faucet, they’re also marketed separately.

Answer (score 3):

That appears to be a garbage disposal chrome trim ring.  Get another one and replace this one.  It's permanently damaged and corroding.  Most of these are chrome-plated brass.  Once the chrome flakes off there is nothing to stop the brass from damage.

I'm not seeing any stainless steel in your photo.

Comment: I'm not seeing "garbage disposal", but otherwise agree 100%. (Every disposal I've had had some sort of engraving/stamping in the drain collar indicating the brand).

Comment: @FreeMan In addition to no branding, the sink appears to be a typical bathroom porcelain sink, not a kitchen sink. There are porcelain kitchen sinks (which never made sense to me - for a bunch of reasons I always go with stainless steel sinks in kitchens) but the size/shape would be different.